# anyway to expand $\sqrt[3]{\tan x+1}$ or $\sqrt[3]{\left(\tan x\right)^{3}+\left(\tan x\right)^{2}-\tan x-1}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following two expressions in $\tan{x}$:

$\sqrt[3]{\tan x+1}$

$\sqrt[3]{\left(\tan x\right)^{3}+\left(\tan x\right)^{2}-\tan x-1}$?

There are trigonometric identities which can be used to express a compound angle as a polynomial in $\tan{x}$, for example $\tan{3x}=\frac{3\tan{x}-\tan^{3}{x}}{1-3\tan^{2}{x}}$ but can these be used to simplify one or both of the above expressions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't simplify the first one, but $(\tan{x}-1)(\tan{x}+1)^{2}=\tan^{3}{x}+\tan^{2}{x}-\tan{x}-1$ so your second expression should (unless I've made an error - it happens) become $((\tan{x}-1)(\tan{x}+1)^{2})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Does this help?

Comment: I basicly wants to simplify tanx + ((tanx−1)(tanx+1)2)1/3 + ((tanx+1)(tanx-1)2)1/3，which equals to ((tanx +1)1/3 + (tanx-1)1/3) / ((tanx +1)1/3 - (tanx-1)1/3) ,and now I'm trying to further simplify it .